# GRASS 6.4.3 Landsat processing

Tags: grass-gis, landsat, change-detection

what are the pre-processing steps required for landsat etm+ with GRASS 6.4.3 prior to land cover change detection? The product used is L1T.

Comment: You can find an overview here: http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/LANDSAT

Answer (score 1):

Landsat 7 will run straight though GRASS. I use the [Win7 version](http://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass70/) though -

[i.landsat.toar](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/i.landsat.toar.html) is the module you want to preprocess with I expect.